# asp.net mvc3 how to switch case dropdownlist and submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, switch-statement

I basically have a switch statement for a dropdownlist but how can I also put an option for my radio buttons there

```
<div style="float:right;">
 <select name="myview">
 <option value="local">Local View</option>
  <option value="national">National View</option>
 </select>
</div>

  <input type="radio" name="mygroup" value="news" />
  <input type="radio" name="mygroup" value="stories" />

public ActionResult myview(string myview)
    {
        switch(myview)
        {
         case "local":
            //my local section
           break;
          case "national":
          //my national section
         }
  }
```

That what I have thus far but as you see I do not have my radio buttons up there how can i incorporate my radio buttons into the mix ? such as

```
switch(myview)
    {
     case "local" && "news":
        //my local section
       break;
      case "national" && "stories":
      //my national section
     }
```

something along those lines any suggestions would be great

Comment: How can string contain two value, case "local" && "news": will never be satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
var var1 = "something";
var var2 = "something_else";
switch(var1 + "|" + var2) {
    case "something|something_else":
        ...
        break;
    case "something|...":
        break;
    case "...|...":
        break;
}
```